# Continuous function on $\mathbb R^n$, equipped with $||.||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, lp-spaces

We know that the set of continuous function on $\mathbb R^n$,
$\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R^n})$ is equipped with $||.||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)}$,

where $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})}:=sup|f(x)|$, s.t $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

My question is, suppose I have an arbitrary function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I want to prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^n}$, **Is it sufficient to only prove that $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})}$ is finite**? So that I get my request to prove?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1, x>0, -1, x<0$ $\|f\|_{L^\infty}=1,$ but f is not a continuous function.

Comment: This is  not a norm. $\|f\|_{\infty}$ may be $\infty$ for a continuous function $f$. Take a simple example like $f(x)=x$ when $n=1$.

Comment: A norm assumes finite values in $\Bbb R$ (the scalar field), but not $+\infty$.